# Django/Python Where to find a list of available filter functions when querying

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm currently working with a Python Django project and in there I filter data from PostgreSQL where I need to find the functions that can be called after each field followed by two underscores.

Ex:

- birthday__year, birthday__month
- start_time__hour, start_time__seconds
- salary__gte, salary__lt

Like wise from where can we get a list of all possibilities (except for foreign key fields) that can be called through the TestObj.objects.filter() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called [*field lookups* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups). You can find a list of *builtin* field lookups in the [documentation on querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups). When writing this answer, the current list of builtin lookups is:

- [**`__exact`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exact);
- [**`__iexact`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iexact);
- [**`__contains`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains);
- [**`__icontains`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains);
- [**`__in`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in);
- [**`__gt`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt);
- [**`__gte`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte);
- [**`__lt`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#lt);
- [**`__lte`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#lte);
- [**`__startswith`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#startswith);
- [**`__istartswith`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith);
- [**`__endswith`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#endswith);
- [**`__iendswith`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iendswith);
- [**`__range`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range);
- [**`__date`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#date);
- [**`__year`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#year);
- [**`__iso_year`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iso-year);
- [**`__month`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#month);
- [**`__day`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#day);
- [**`__week`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#week);
- [**`__week_day`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#week-day);
- [**`__quarter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#quarter);
- [**`__time`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#time);
- [**`__hour`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#hour);
- [**`__minute`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#minute);
- [**`__second`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#second);
- [**`__isnull`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull);
- [**`__regex`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#regex); and
- [**`__iregex`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iregex).

Note that you can implement your [own field lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-lookups/) as well. Indeed, you can define a lookup and how to map that to a database query. Certain Django packages for example might provide an extra set of field lookups.

The set of lookups is thus *not* "fixed". You can add lookups if you often need to retrieve/filter a certain condition, and there exists no builtin lookup for that.